# Why is the grass under a temporary skating rink green when the rest of the lawn is dormant brown?

Tags: grass, overwintering, protection, lawn

We installed a temporary skating rink with a white poly liner early in the winter. Today we drained the water and removed the plastic to find that the grass beneath was bright green. The rest of the lawn is brown as is typical for this time of year. The plastic obviously protected the grass somehow, but can anyone fill me in on the exact reasons?

Comment: Found this interesting so did a search. Another person reported the same thing and says it's because the grass goes dormant. I guess having a somewhat consistent cold temperature helps it stay in dormancy. See https://www.pinterest.com/pin/64950419599397957/

Comment: Same thing is happening at my backyard, I have a raised bed (4x2 ft) 1 feet above the ground and the grass underneath is best grass of the whole back yard. could be related to getting partial sun instead of harsh Florida sun.

Answer (score 8):

If you are in a place that's so consistently cold that it occurs to you to set up a backyard skating rink that means it gets *really* cold throughout the winter. What the ice and plastic has done is insulated the grass below from the wind and colder temperature. It may seem counter intuitive but the ice was actually helping keep the cold wind from lowering the temperature of the ground, so that the grass could survive the winter better and come out of hibernation faster.

Comment: Plastic also keeps the evaporation rate down, so unlike on the rest of your lawn, the leaf-blades under the poly liner are not freeze-dried.